# Fontawesome does not print some characters

Tags: fontawesome

I don't know exactly when, but some time ago the fontawesome package started to misbehave: some symbols are not printed on the pdf. No error is issued but there is no symbol in the pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
text \faInfo
\end{document}
```

Here the previous code produces a pdf with only "text" and no symbol. This only happens for some symbol.

How can I debug this?

Comment: This code appears to work fine on my TeX Live (up-to-date). (I assume you want the blobby black letter i) Suggestions: (1) make sure your distribution is up to date; (2) see if you can see anything "suspicious" in the log. Please indicate whether you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, too.

Comment: I'm using LuaLaTeX and my distribution is updated. Tex Live 2014 on a Linux machine. I'll add a log to the question.

Comment: yes. If you use LuaLaTeX it will be working.

Comment: you may have an older version of the font installed system wide that takes precedence over the one that comes with TeX Live. Could you check if you have the font installed as a system font and if it's the case update it to the last version to see if the symbol comes back?

Comment: OK. I've removed the system font and it works now. Thank you all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was an issue due to duplicate font files on the OP's system